# putting multiple array values into database with php and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays

I have multidimensional array where i want to put into the database. Whenever I inserted the array only one of them will be inserted.

Here is my php code

```
$itemsselected = $_GET['chkvalues'];
$total = $_GET['total'];
// check if the parameters are set
if(isset($itemsselected) && isset($total)){
  $ducketNumber = mt_rand(100000,999999);
  $values['TotalAmount'] = $total;
  $values['DucketNumber'] = $ducketNumber;
  foreach((array)$itemsselected as $key => $item){
    list($id,$itemName,$itemQty,$itemPrice,$subtotal) = explode("/",$item);
    //**********  Insert a record into another table  ************
    $sql = "INSERT INTO customerorderdetails(docketNumber, itemOrdered, Quantity, UnitPrice,totalAmount, CreatedBy) values ('$ducketNumber', '$itemName', '$itemQty','$itemPrice','$subtotal','$user')";
    CustomQuery($sql);          
  }
}
```

my HTML

```
<table id='orderTable'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Qty</td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td>SubTotal</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id='item'>
      <td><input type='hidden' class='name' value='pencil' />pencil</td>
      <td><input type='hidden' class='qty' value='2' />2</td>
      <td><input type='hidden' class='price' value='10' />10</td>
      <td><input type='hidden' class='subtotal' value='20' />20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='item'>
      <td><input type='hidden' class='name' value='pen' />pen</td>
      <td><input type='hidden' class='qty' value='3' />3</td>
      <td><input type='hidden' class='price' value='15' />15</td>
      <td><input type='hidden' class='subtotal' value='45' />45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='item'>
      <td><input type='hidden' class='name' value='ruler' />ruler</td>
      <td><input type='hidden' class='qty' value='1' />1</td>
      <td><input type='hidden' class='price' value='20' />20</td>
      <td><input type='hidden' class='subtotal' value='20' />20</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <p>
    <label>total</label>
    <input type='text' name='total' id='cart_total' value='' />
    <input type='button' name='btn' id='btn' />
```

total sum up the subtotal,
and here is my jQuery

```
var itemArr =[];
var total = $('#cart_total').val();
//alert(total);
// get the order placed
$('#orderTable tbody tr.item').each(function(){
  var order_item_name = $(this).find('.name').val();
  var order_item_qty = $(this).find('.qty').val();
  var order_item_price = $(this).find('.price').val();
  var order_item_subtotal = $(this).find('.subtotal').val();
  //order_item_subtotal.val(order_item_qty * order_item_price);
  var itemselected = order_item_id+"/"+order_item_name+"/"+order_item_qty+"/"+order_item_price+"/"+order_item_subtotal;
  if(itemselected !== undefined && itemselected !== null){
    //itemArr.push(JSON.stringify(itemselected));
    itemArr.push(itemselected);
  }
});
itemArr.join(',');
alert(itemArr);
alert(itemArr.length);
document.location.href = "customerorder_add.php?chkvalues="+itemArr+"&total="+total;
```

What is it that I did wrong? needs assistant.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please can i get ny help? this is my sql printout        "INSERT INTO customerorderdetails(docketNumber, itemOrdered, Quantity, UnitPrice,totalAmount, CreatedBy) values ('669424', 'egusi and amala', '1','250.00','250,1dk','Asibi')". notice that it join the first part of the second array value to the end of the first array value - '250,1dk' please can somebody tell me why it is like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first: I think you have an issue with the . and the # in your code.
In jquery, "." is for class and # is for id

In your html: i'm assuming that you should call these "class", not "id"; also: "id" if it's really what you wanted to write should *always* be unique.

Comment: sorry it is class, i have just edited my code, thanks